# CORS problem,using axios,how can this be possible?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, go, axios, cors

I'm using gin to be my backend,and this is my cors middleware code.

```golang
func Cors() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        method := ctx.Request.Method
        if method == "OPTIONS" {
            ctx.Header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000")
            ctx.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            ctx.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS")
            ctx.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Cookie,Authorization,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method,Origin,Referer,Sec-Fetch-Dest,Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding,Sec-Fetch-Mode,Sec-Fetch-Site,User-Agent,Pragma,Host,Connection,Cache-Control,Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding,X-Requested-With,X-Forwarded-For,X-Forwarded-Host,X-Forwarded-Proto,X-Forwarded-Port,X-Forwarded-Prefix,X-Real-IP,Accept")
            ctx.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ctx.Request.Header.Get("origin"))
            ctx.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusNoContent)
            return
        }
        ctx.Next()
    }
}
```

In the frontend,I'm using the axios to request,and I'm using React to develop my app.
Below is my setting about axios.

```js
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8000";

axios.defaults.baseURL = BASE_URL;
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

and I abstracted a function to do a POST request

```js
async function post<T = any, D = any>(
    url: string,
    data?: T,
    headers?: AxiosRequestHeaders
): Promise<D> {
    const res = await axios.post(url, data, {
        headers: headers,
    });
    if (res.status === 200) return Promise.resolve(res.data);
    else return Promise.reject(res.statusText);
}
```

it's interesting when I requesting on Chrome.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcn7X.png)

I truly got a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header but it just said I didn't get this header in respond.

It's really weired and I don't know how to do.

Comment: You need to supply some of the CORS headers for the actual request, not only the preflight. (Your browser sends 2 requests, one first to check CORS-headers, then the actual request comes after that).

Comment: By the way I'm using webpack devserver

Comment: @super Thanks for comment,I know that browser sends 2 requests.What's the meaning of supplying some of the CORS headers for the actual request?Aren't they automatically provided by the browser?

Comment: @SnowWarrior Unconditionally reflecting the request's origin in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header and allowing credentials is insecure! See https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties. Please stop and take the time to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You try this

```
  // CORS - cors enable
func CORS(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
    c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
    c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    if c.Request.Method == http.MethodOptions {
        c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusNoContent)
        return
    }
    c.Next()
}
```

Comment: The wildcard cannot be used in conjunction with credentialed requests. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Answer (score -1):

When different origin,we need always to put Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in responses' headers.And if we Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,this should be put in responses' headers too.

middleware should be changed like below:

```golang
func Cors() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        method := ctx.Request.Method
        if method == "OPTIONS" {
            ctx.Header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000")
            ctx.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            ctx.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS")
            ctx.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ctx.Request.Header.Get("origin"))
            ctx.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Cookie,Authorization,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method,Origin,Referer,Sec-Fetch-Dest,Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding,Sec-Fetch-Mode,Sec-Fetch-Site,User-Agent,Pragma,Host,Connection,Cache-Control,Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding,X-Requested-With,X-Forwarded-For,X-Forwarded-Host,X-Forwarded-Proto,X-Forwarded-Port,X-Forwarded-Prefix,X-Real-IP,Accept")
            ctx.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusNoContent)
            return
        }
        ctx.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ctx.Request.Header.Get("origin"))
        ctx.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        ctx.Next()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, like that. If you are using `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to include cross-origin cookies please be aware that some browsers block this by default so it will not work for all clients.

Comment: Don't blindly reflect the request's origin in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, esp. if you're also allowing credentials. Doing so is very insecure, as show in https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties